# Is there any way to append a query string to googlesyndication.com ad safeframe?

Tags: javascript, ads, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

Is there any way to append a query string to googlesyndication.com generated safeframe url? Something like: https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-36/html/container.html?foo=bar

I've seen some sites doing it.

My code looks like:

```html
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"</script>

<script>
  window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('MY_SLOT_ID', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1573813015782-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>

<div id='div-gpt-ad-1573813015782-0'>
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1573813015782-0'); });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: could you precise us the aim of this set up ? There might be another way to achieve your goal without having to mess with the generic script generated url.

Comment: @rabsom thank's for helping. The aim of this set up is to whitelist this url for adblock. Adblock blocks all those url related with ads. To unblock urls I have to add a query string prameter ?foo=bar in each url.  In this case adblock is blocking the safeframe created by google, so I need to add ?foo=bar to the safeframe url. Let me know if you want me to go more deeply